# Emberjs handlebars content binding edit field not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, observers

I have an emberJS object, viewed by an editablefield view, in order to be able to edit it with bindings.
I modify the view in order to be able to replace links in the text.
My problem is that if I use the inside views (Zs.RealValue) render function, it won't refresh on each update, like the simple {{value}} would do, only if I erase the text and after erase the first change.

I have a simple example here:

Steps to do: double click on one of the edit fields, the edit box appears, try modify the value, you will see, that the simple view is being updated, but not the other text view.

http://jsfiddle.net/symunona/hCjEc/7/

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because you try to implement the `render` function yourself in `RealValue`. If you change `RealValue` to just this:

```
Zs.RealValue = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{value}}")
});
```

then the [example works](http://jsfiddle.net/hCjEc/9/).

Comment: This is my problem! I want to change the value itself when rendered. I would like to change the value to be viewed in a different way, so i.e. when there is a link in the value, I want to change it into a HTML link. I do not see, how can I do it with the compile.